# Disallowing printf in child process

Tags: c, linux

I've got a cmd line app in C under Linux that has to run another process, the problem is that the child process prints a lot in a comand line and the whole app gets messy.

Is it possible to disallow child process to print anything in cmd line from parent process? It would be very helpful to for example being able to define a command that allows or disallows printing by a child process.

Comment: Close the childs stdout.

Comment: @KamilCuk Redirecting to /dev/null might be a better idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's the time-honoured tradition of just redirecting the output to the bit bucket<sup>(a)</sup>, along the lines of:

```
system("runChild >/dev/null 2>&1");
```

Or, if you're doing it via `fork/exec`, simply redirect the file handles using `dup2` between the `fork` and `exec`.

It won't stop a *determined* child from outputting to your standard output but it will have to be very tricky to do that.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I'm not usually a big fan of that, just in case something goes wrong. I'd prefer to redirect it to a *real* file which can be examined later if need be (and deleted eventually if not).

Answer (score 0):

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

On recent Linux, every [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) is in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format (except `init` or `systemd`; play with [pstree(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) or [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) is running in a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) started by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (or [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)...) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

You might use cleverly [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) with [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) to redirect `STDOUT_FILENO` to `/dev/null` (see [null(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html), [stdout(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html), [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html))

> I've got a cmd line app in C under Linux that has to run another process, the problem is that the child process prints a lot in a comand line

I would instead provide a way to *selectively* redirect the child process' output. You could use [program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) or environment variables (see [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) and/or [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)) to provide such an option to your user.

An example of such a command program starting and redirecting subprocesses and redirecting them is your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (see [gcc(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html); it runs `cc1` and [as(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/as.1.html) and [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html)...). Consider downloading and studying its source code.

Study also -for inspiration- the source code of some [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (e.g. [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell)), or write your own one.